# Data output on Console instead of GUI

Tags: java, database, jdbc, jframe, jtable

I was trying to populate database's data into jtable, however when i run the code, data was showed on console instead of being on the Jframe. This is the console output:

```
93203 , KERN , ARVIN , CA , 2012 , 12 , All Ages , 83 , 59.4 , 41.5 , 50.5
93203 , KERN , ARVIN , CA , 2012 , 12 , Adults (18+) , 29 , 59.4 , 41.5 , 50.5
93210 , FRESNO , COALINGA , CA , 2012 , 1 , Children (0-17) , 58 , 64.9 , 36.1 , 50.5
93210 , FRESNO , COALINGA , CA , 2012 , 1 , All Ages , 99 , 64.9 , 36.1 , 50.5
93210 , FRESNO , COALINGA , CA , 2012 , 1 , Adults (18+) , 41 , 64.9 , 36.1 , 50.5
93210 , FRESNO , COALINGA , CA , 2012 , 2 , Children (0-17) , 58 , 66.9 , 38.4 , 52.7
93210 , FRESNO , COALINGA , CA , 2012 , 2 , All Ages , 99 , 66.9 , 38.4 , 52.7
93210 , FRESNO , COALINGA , CA , 2012 , 2 , Adults (18+) , 41 , 66.9 , 38.4 , 52.7
93210 , FRESNO , COALINGA , CA , 2012 , 3 , Adults (18+) , 41 , 68.6 , 42.2 , 55.4
93210 , FRESNO , COALINGA , CA , 2012 , 3 , Children (0-17) , 58 , 68.6 , 42.2 , 55.4
93210 , FRESNO , COALINGA , CA , 2012 , 3 , All Ages , 99 , 68.6 , 42.2 , 55.4
```

here is the code for the GUI

```
public class WeatherFrame extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTable table;
    HealthData health = new HealthData();
    private DefaultTableModel model;
    String[] columnNames = {"zipcode", "county", "city", "state", "year", "month","ageGroup",
                            "numOfVisits", "MonthlyMax", "MonthlyMin", "MonthlyNor"};

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    WeatherFrame frame = new WeatherFrame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public WeatherFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 800, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBounds(100, 100,750, 200);
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(6, 25, 788, 180);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane);

        model = new DefaultTableModel();
        populateTable();
        table = new JTable(model);

        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

        JButton btnInsert = new JButton("insert");
        btnInsert.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        btnInsert.setBounds(315, 217, 117, 29);
        contentPane.add(btnInsert);

        JButton btnDelete = new JButton("delete");
        btnDelete.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        btnDelete.setBounds(198, 243, 117, 29);
        contentPane.add(btnDelete);

        JButton btnSearch = new JButton("search");
        btnSearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        btnSearch.setBounds(81, 243, 117, 29);
        contentPane.add(btnSearch);

        JLabel lblWeatherTable = new JLabel("Weather Table");
        lblWeatherTable.setBounds(149, 6, 107, 16);
        contentPane.add(lblWeatherTable);

        JButton btnNext = new JButton("update");
        btnNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        btnNext.setBounds(198, 217, 117, 29);
        contentPane.add(btnNext);

        JButton btnRefresh = new JButton("refresh");
        btnRefresh.setBounds(81, 217, 117, 29);
        contentPane.add(btnRefresh);
    }

    public void populateTable() {

        for(String name: columnNames)
            model.addColumn(name);
        for (int i = 0; i < health.showAllData().size(); i++) {
            int zipcode = health.showAllData().get(i).getZipCode();
            String county = health.showAllData().get(i).getCounty();
            String city = health.showAllData().get(i).getCity();
            String state = health.showAllData().get(i).getState();
            int year = health.showAllData().get(i).getYear();
            int month = health.showAllData().get(i).getMonth();
            String ageGroup = health.showAllData().get(i).getAgeGroup();
            int numVisit = health.showAllData().get(i).getNumOfVisits();
            float max = health.showAllData().get(i).getMMax();
            float min = health.showAllData().get(i).getMMin();
            float nor = health.showAllData().get(i).getMNor();

            Object[] data = {zipcode, county, city, state, year, month, ageGroup, numVisit, max, min, nor};
            model.addRow(data);
        }

    }
}
```

I'm not sure why data doesn't output on the Jframe, Can someone suggest a way to fix this. Thank you in advance. 
I think the error is in the populateTable method, but I test variables inside the for loop and correct data was passed into those local variable, so Im a little stuck on figuring out where the logical error is.When I execute this code while populating the data into Jtable, the java application appear on task bar but there is no frame.

[image]

I used several println to check wether data was passed in to local variables in the second for loop inside populateTable method and they all were passed in. There does not seem to be anything wrong with the statement to add data to model either, so I cant really figured out why it isn't working. Can data overflow the table size?

Comment: You're probably running the `main` method of another class.

Comment: It is not the problem because I set the main method of this class to be the launcher of the project

Comment: Also, The program worked correctly and the GUI shows columns' names before I populated data into the table, After I populated the data everything broke.

Comment: Can you post the code for the `HealthData` class ?

Comment: sorry, I cant post the HealthData class since it wasn't mine, but we tested that class and it worked properly

Comment: There may be a System.out.println() method within the showAllDate() method contained within the HealthData class. After all....it does say showAllData. Try removing the showAllData:  health.get(i)......

Comment: so I took out the println line in show data but the Frame still wont show anything

Comment: You call `health.showAllData()` a lot of times - consider calling it ONCE in populate Table, store the result in a variable and work with that.

Comment: Yes I will do that, but i don't think the problem came from there, I did several println in the loops to test if correct data was passed into the local variables and they all did, I just dont know why when I try to put them into Object[] and then add Object[] into the table, everything broke

Comment: I see the column names of the table. So the code is executing. If you don't see the data, then you have not data in your HealthData class. Also, don't use a null laout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Add the label to the BorderLayout.PAGE_START, the scroll pane to BorderLayout.CENTER, then create a panel for the buttons add the buttons to the panel and the panel to the BorderLayout.PAGE_END

Comment: @camickr check by printing out local variables in the second for loops, and there was data which was passed into those local variables, so I don't even know why the code doesn't execute.

Comment: it is possible that because the HealthData class was connecting to the database in its constructor, so when I create a new HealthData object, it was still waiting for connection to be establish